# How to fix "Element is not clickable at point" using RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

Using RSelenium, I am trying to fill out a form and download a zipfile.
However, I am having issues selecting the checkboxes required to download the document.

I get the following error: "RSelenium Element is not clickable at point (x,y) Other element would receive the click".

After extensively googling, I found only one question about this error in in the context of RSelenium. The error was caused by a popup, but my page does not have any popups showing up, so I do not know what might be causing this.

Although there are several answers for the error I am fiding for Python, I could not find an answer for RSelenium.

Any idea why I cannot click on the checkbox agreeing with the terms and conditions?

```
#On my Linux terminal, I create the docker:
sudo docker run -d -p 4445:4444 -p 5901:5900 -v /home/john/test:/home/seluser/Downloads selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1

#Then, in R:

library(RSelenium)
ePrefs <- makeFirefoxProfile(
  list(
    browser.download.dir = "/home/seluser/Downloads",
    "browser.download.folderList" = 2L,
    "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting" = FALSE,
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" = "multipart/x-zip,application/zip,application/x-zip-compressed,application/x-compressed,application/msword,application/csv,text/csv,image/png ,image/jpeg, application/pdf, text/html,text/plain,  application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/x-excel, application/x-msexcel, application/octet-stream"))

mybrowser <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = ePrefs, port = 4445)
mybrowser$open()

url<-paste("http://www.cis.es/cis/opencms/EN/formulario.jsp?dwld=/Microdatos/MD3288.zip",sep="")

#start navigation
mybrowser$navigate(url)
wxbox<-mybrowser$findElement(using="id","Nombre")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("FirstName"))

wxbox<-mybrowser$findElement(using="id","Apellidos")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("LastName"))

wxbox<-mybrowser$findElement(using="id","profesion")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("University"))

wxbox<-mybrowser$findElement(using="id","Email")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("some_email@gmail.com"))

chkbox <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//input[@name='objeto1'][@type='checkbox']")
chkbox$clickElement()

chkbox <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//input[@name='Terminos'][@type='checkbox']")
chkbox$clickElement()
#But then I get an error right after this command:
#Selenium message:Element is not clickable at point (61.866668701171875, 715.38330078125). Other element would receive the click: <label for="Terminos"></label>

#Just to make sure all the rest of the commands were working, I took a screen-shot
mybrowser$screenshot(display = TRUE) #as we can see, not even the first checkbox seemed to have worked, although I got no error for that one

#If it was not for the error, my plan was to continue like this:
donwload <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'class', "button")
donwload$clickElement()

list.files("/home/john/test/") #hopefully, the zipfile would be here
```

Any ideas why I am getting this "Element is not clickable" even though I have no popups? How would I fix that using RSelenium?

Comment: So are you running the selenium server inside a docker container? Did you check for the downloaded file inside the container? Or just in your personal home directory? What OS are you running?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use Linux, but I am very new to Docker, I am not sure how it works yet. Before the code I shared, I ran in my Linux terminal two commands:
sudo docker run hello-world and
sudo docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
So I guess I am using Docker, I just do not know how to access the files.